# rsync could not find xattr #1 for {file}... error in rsync protocol data stream

Tags: rsync

I have regular and frequent backups from a set of QNAP systems to a central backups repository. Backups are `rsync` over `ssh`, pulled from the central server. The QNAP filesystem is `ext4`, shared to my users via Samba. (QNAPs are based on Linux, and I'm fairly confident that for the purposes of this question you can treat them as such.) The filesystem on the backups server also handles extended attributes.

Recently I've been getting this fatal error from one of them

```
[sender] could not find xattr #1 for long_filename.xlsm
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at xattrs.c(622) [sender=3.1.2]
rsync: [generator] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

The `rsync` command is driven from `rsnapshot` but it comes down to this

```
rsync -avzSAXiv --delete --numeric-ids --fake-super --fuzzy --delete-after --partial --link-dest=/path/to/previous user@remoteHost:/share/ /path/to/backup/
```

Extended attributes on the source file

```
getfattr -d -m - long_filename.xlsm
# file: long_filename.xlsm
security.NTACL=0sAwADAA..........AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAASAZAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAnAAAAAEFAAAAAAAFFQAAABSYSwXsMclxQXR48kIFAAABBQAAAAAABR....................IBAgAAAgAc..........QA/wEfAAEBAAAAAAABAAAAAA==
user.DOSATTRIB=0sMH..............EQAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKZ........YBAAAAAAAAAAA=
user.qtier="io_aware"
```

What is this `xattr #1`? Is it referring to extended attributes on the remote server or on the local destination? What might I be looking for, to identify the problem? The destination file doesn't exist, because that's where `rsync` crashed out, but 87000 or so other files successfully transferred. Nothing seems to be particularly special about the source file.

I'm currently trying to build an MRE but until I found the `security.NTACL` attribute I was failing dismally (`getfattr` only displays `user.*` attributes by default).

Thanks

Comment: Depending on how old your `rsync` version is, it could be [this bug](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9594). Note that the reporter added a way to reproduce it too, that might help you check if is a regression for example.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani thank you. I've got 3.1.2 on both ends. Checking the steps to reproduce...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem (with rsync 3.1.3):

```
[sender] could not find xattr #1 for ...
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at xattrs.c(750) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Upgrading to the current rsync version (3.2.3) seems to solve the problem, however, another problem obviously related to the filesystem used (HFS+) has [appeared](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/107).

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm now trying to find 3.2.3 for my QNAP!